# Background-color on Samsung Internet application

Tags: css

```css
body {
  background-color:  #4dc6ff;
 }
 
  
  .paragrafacasa {
   width: 500px;
   margin-right: auto;
   margin-left: auto;
   background-color: #e8e8e8;
   border: 2px solid black;
   border-radius: 8px;
   margin-top: 100px;
  }

  .paragrafacasa p {
   font-size: 30px;
   text-align: center;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title> Here is title </title>
</head>
<body>
 <div class="paragrafacasa">
  <p> Here is my text </p>
 </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Just finished editing a site, but when I published the Samsung Internet application do not display `background-color` on `div`.

Everything is displayed correctly in Chrome, only the Samsung Internet encounters this problem. Below I attached 2 screenshots to understand better. Any solution?

[Samsung Internet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dUL8L.jpg) ,
  [Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FlDt8.jpg)

Comment: Hey maybe reupload your screen shot, it seems they can't be display easily on stack over flow via imgur

Comment: You have to include your CSS too

Comment: "background-color:  #ffffff94;" this is invalid color value. In hexa format should 3 or 6 digit allow to render proper color.

Comment: Hm, but why in Chrome this color value is diplayed correctly? I chose this color with inspect element in Google Chrome.

Comment: Just changed my background-color and I'm still experiencing this problem on the Samsung Internet application.